# Finding Chain Homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology now.The book is very understandable till now.The main problem I am having is when finding a chain homotopy between two chain complexes.It feels like he is coming up with the corresponding maps like magic.I logically understand they work but I have no idea how to reasonably find it out.Is it about trial and error or there is something behind this kind of things that I need to know about.Thank You.
edit:I have reasonable background for a graduate student.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? For instance, give an example of such chain homotopies you don't know where they come from, because it is likely that some of them have the same intuition while some others come from a very different idea.

Comment: @javi like prism operator in the proof of homotopy invariance of homology,chain homotopy of subdivision operator with identity, chain homotopy equivalence of inclusion in the proof of excision.

Answer (score 1):

There is, in fact, a magic chain homotopy theorem (that's how I always thought of it) called the *Acyclic Models Theorem*. You can find versions of it in Spanier's book "Algebraic Topology", and [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_model#Statement_of_the_theorem). I believe that Spanier's book actually applies the Acyclic Models Theorem to one or more of the cases listed in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a somewhat more geometric and conceptual interpretation of chain homotopy. Define the complex $I_\bullet$ to be
$$...\to 0 \to I_1 \to I_0 \to 0 \to \cdots$$
where $I_1 = \mathbb Z e_0e_1$, $I_0 = \mathbb Z e_0 + \mathbb Z e_1$, and the nonzero boundary map is given by $\partial(e_0e_1) = e_1 - e_0$. This is the simplicial complex associated to the interval. Then a chain map $K: C_\bullet \otimes I_\bullet \to D_\bullet$ is the same thing as a pair of maps $K(-,e_i): C_\bullet \to D_\bullet$ as well as a chain homotopy $K(-,e_0e_1): C_\bullet \to D_{\bullet +1}$.

Geometrically, the tensor product of chain complexes models the product of spaces (see e.g. the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem). This suggests the relationship between maps $X\times [0,1] \to Y$ and chain homotopies on the corresponding complexes for $X$ and $Y$.

Now let’s investigate the prism chain homotopy concretely. Given maps $f_0, f_1: X \to Y$ and a homotopy $H: [0,1]\times X \to Y$ between them, we want to construct a chain homotopy, i.e. a map $K: C_\bullet(X) \otimes I_\bullet \to C_\bullet(Y)$. Our map should have $K(-,e_i) = (f_i)_\ast$. By definition of the tensor product, if we want a chain map, we should assign $K(\sigma, e_0e_1)$ to an object whose boundary is the (signed) sum of $K(\partial \sigma, e_0e_1)$ and $K(\sigma, e_i)$. Starting with $\sigma=p$ a zero-simplex, we will want to assign $K(p, e_0e_1)$ to the singular 1-simplex $H(-,p)$, whose boundary is $f_1(p) - f_0(p)$. Inductively, this suggests defining $K(\sigma, e_0e_1)$ as a prism interpolating $f_1(\sigma)$ and $f_0(\sigma)$, i.e. the prism $H(-,\sigma)$. The usual formula is just triangulating that prism.